# Google maps geocoding works but not the right way

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a company listing template and want to show the location of the company in a Google maps. This is my first time working with the Google Maps API and my code works. But I know that I do not do it the exact right way at the moment.

```
<script>

    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var address = '<?php Here I give the address from my database by PHP ?>';
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        }
      });  

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('big_map'), mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   

</script>

<div id="big_map"></div>
```

I want to specify the `mapOptions` `center` by the `results[0].geometry.location`, but I can't get it work.

As I said, my code works but maybe someone can tell me how I can do it a better way, because I know this is not 100% correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Your current code is the best you can do,  and it's 100% correct. When you want to use the location returned by the geocoder directly in the map-options you must create the map-instance inside the geocode-callback. But the result would be the same, except that it would take more time until the map has been rendered.

Comment: Okay, but that's what I tried. To create the map-instance in the geocode-callback. But if you say that rendering is slower then. Then I keep it as it is. The only thing that is not correct now, is that I have a default latlng from Australia. So if a address is not found he shows the Australia map. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct, but you must specify a center for a map, it's a required property. When the geocoding fails, you must use a fallback-location instead(but the result would be the same as I said). When you want to have another default-center, define another. It would also be possible to use geolocation to retrieve the user's address and use this as a fallback. But the issue would be the same, geolocation may fail too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the order to get "map", like this...
First:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng
    }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('big_map'), mapOptions);
```

Second:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think if you center the point with **mapOptions**, you could delete **map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);** and **position: results[0].geometry.location**.
And try it too with "my order" :)

Comment: No because I need the Geo coding. So the address.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, and it worked:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script>
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('big_map'), mapOptions);

        //var address = '<?php Here I give the address from my database by PHP ?>';
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'Somewhere'}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });  

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   

</script>
<div id="big_map" class="googleMapsMunicipios"></div>
```

For more information visit:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?hl=es